# Word wrap hyphenated text as if it were one word

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to wrap hyphenated text on a button as if it were one word. I've tried using a few different variations of the `word-wrap` and `break-word` CSS properties but no luck.

In the snippet below, I'm trying to get `hello` on one line, and `this-is-a-test` on the next line

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.innerHTML = 'hello this-is-a-test'
```

```css
#btn {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn"></button>
```

Comment: I think Андрій Палій's answer to use a non-breaking hyphen is another good option, but both that and my answer depend on what your _real_ button text is going to be like. Is that use of spaces and hyphens typical? or are you (as I assumed) just using the hyphens in `hello this-is-a-test` to create a long word where you might really want spaces. Could you give several real examples instead of a single test example?

Answer (score 1):

In place of your dashes in this-is-a-test you could use non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;` and you could explicitly put a `<br>` where the space is. If you have arbitrary text (not a test) you could start with what you have then regex replace `&nbsp;` wherever there is a `-` dash, and replace space   with `<br>`

```js
let btnText = 'hello this-is-a-test';
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.innerHTML = btnText.replaceAll('-','&nbsp;').replaceAll(' ','<br>');
```

```css
#btn {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace dashes with &#8209; symbol. Like:

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.innerHTML = 'hello this-is-a-test'.replace('/-/g', '&#8209;')
```

Comment: You should mention that `&#8209;` is a _Non-Breaking Hyphen_, Unicode Character (U+2011) `&#x2011;`